# How to search an Array containing struct elements in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, ios8

It's kind pretty straight forward to find an element in an array with type String, Int, etc.

```
var States = ["CA", "FL", "MI"]
var filteredStates = States.filter {$0 == "FL"} // returns false, true, false
```

Now, I created a struct

```
struct Candy{
    let name:String
}
```

and then initialized it

```
var candies =  [Candy(name: "Chocolate"),
Candy(name: "Lollipop"),
Candy(name: "Caramel")]
```

Can anyone please suggest the right way to find "Chocolate" in the array containing struct elements? I'm not able to implement the find or filter method.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With the following code you receive all candy structs in the array, which match to `"Chocolate"`.

```
var candiesFiltered = candies.filter{$0.name == "Chocolate"}
```

If you just want a boolean if it has been found or not you could use the following code:

```
var found = candies.filter{$0.name == "Chocolate"}.count > 0
```

Comment: The syntax can be simplified as `filter { $0.name == ... }` since the closure is 'trailing'.

Comment: Is it possible to also filter with a dynamic string? something like:

`var candiesFiltered = candies.filter{$0[customProperty] == "Chocolate"}`

Comment: can we use to || operator inside the filter block? I need to compare fromString & toString