# How to substitute string name from a struct with its corresponding image name?

Tags: swift, uitableview, struct

I have a struct to store name and image names of pictures which are already bundled in app as follows

```
struct City { var name: String
              var imageName: String }

class firstViewController: UIViewController

let cities = [City(name:"City00", imageName:"city_00"),
              City(name:"City01", imageName:"city_01"),
              City(name:"City02", imageName:"city_02")]
```

In displayViewController, I have a variable `nowCityImages` to store data selected from firstViewcontroller

```
class displayViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var nowCityImages: [String] = []
```

Now I want to display image of city in tableview

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CityCell

    let outCityImages = nowCityImages[indexPath.item]

    // This is not displaying any images
     myCell.cityImage.image = UIImage(named:outCityImages)

   return myCell
}
```

If I use  `print(outCityImages)`, I am getting following output as excepted

```
City00
City02
```

but I don't know how to replace `City00 with city_00` and `City02 with city_02` in tableview cell so that it displays the image.

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665122/how-to-search-an-array-containing-struct-elements-in-swift

Comment: @JimmyJames, that question is for searching, I am looking for substituting

Comment: Check the statement where you add or append strings to nowCityImages. It should be similar to city.imageName not city.name. e.g. nowCityImages.append(cities[0].imageName)

Answer (score 0):

if the number at the end is 2 digit length:

```
var str = "City00"
let index = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)

var str1 = str.substring(to: index).lowercased()
var str2 = str.substring(from: index)
let name = "\(str1)_\(str2)" //city_00
```

Comment: That is not always the case, I just gave an example to spell out my problem.I like to know how to substitute corresponding names of cities I am getting with their image names.

Comment: In displayViewController, there is the city name only. I think you might pass City object/imageName to displayViewController rather than the city name only or create a method to get city object by city name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change to code of getting nowCityImages to this

```
    var nowCityImages: [String] = cities.filter(){$0.imageName}
```

Now it will return image name as you want.